# How does Google Chrome manage to freeze my entire PC?

Tags: windows, google-chrome

Google Chrome is the only program on my computer that can freeze my mouse.  When loading multiple tabs at once, the mouse pointer will become unresponsive, and nothing is moving on my screen.  I've never seen any other program do this.  My PC usually emits a little beep when it's done thinking.

This happens on Windows 7 on every single computer that I own.  I don't own expensive hardware, but I have Core i3's and i5's with plentiful RAM.  I know that Chrome runs as multiple processes (one for each tab I believe.)  Could this cause the issue?  Are the processes running at a higher priority than, say, the mouse drivers?

This isn't a huge problem, but I am curious about the technical reasons that cause this phenomenon.

Thanks!

Comment: I would say bad reasource managment by the operating system. On linux I have a bunch of software that can freeze everything, but browsers are quite well represented.

Comment: 'This happens on Windows 7 on every single computer that I own' - OK, that lets out bad drivers, hardware issues.  The only other thing I can think of is 'Chrome is crap'.

Comment: Could be. Or Chrome could be the reverse and successfully use all resources it is given. And if you load more tabs at the same time then it just uses more resources and is faster ready with it.

Answer (score 3):

Every extension, tab, etc. in chrome runs as a new process. This, and the actual chrome processes. For example, having 6 pages open and three plugins brings this:

[image]

This is part of what makes chrome so fast. However, all these process can bog down a lower-end PC. Running a lot of tabs with webpages that use other resource-intensive programs such as java or flash can even bog down a high-end PC like mine.

Answer (score 3):

A popular solution is to upgrade your realtek driver to 6.0.1.6662 (R2.71) founded by the google team
http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/71CLxvV8VPo%5B1-25-false%5D

> It does seem that the issue is linked back to a conflict with the
>   Realtek audio driver that may be currently installed on your machine.
>   We've seen reports that upgrading to the driver version 6.0.1.6662
>   (R2.71) will likely solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's either out of RAM, disk thrashing or crashing the video driver.

Answer (score 0):

Probably caused by some random Chrome bug that causes all RAM to be captured by Chrome. When it happens with Linux, I can force kill the process and everything is fine again. In case of Linux I have to use key combination [Right Alt]+[SysRq]+f to kill the chrome process because the UI is too slow to be usable. I'm not sure if Windows has some equivalent key combination to kill the process eating most memory.